# Difference between HomographyBasedEstimator and findHomography OpenCV

Tags: opencv, image-processing, homography, opencv-stitching

I am trying to write a program that stitches images using SURF detector and I would like to know the difference between the two homography estimator. 
I understand `findHomography` uses RANSAC, is `HomographyBasedEstimator` using RANSAC too?

If it isn't, would someone point me to the paper `HomographyBasedEstimator` used?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

The main difference between both functions is that `findHomography`, as the name says, is used to find an homography, and `HomographyBasesEstimator` uses an already existing homographies to calculate the rotation of the cameras.

I mean, `HomographyBasesEstimator` doesn't find the homographies, it use them to do the computation of camera motion and all the other camera parameters such as focal lengths and optical centers.

I hope this can help you.

Comment: HomographyBasesEstimator takes only features and their pairwise matches, it doesn't take an already computed homography... 
Also, if it's used to estimate the camera parameters, why is bundle adjustment used after the homography estimator? (for example in the panorama stitcher).

Answer (score 3):

Actually, findHomography has been called in BestOf2NearestMatcher.

Answer (score 2):

Documentation doesn't seem to say, but it suggests that `HomographyBasedEstimator` finds a rotation matrix, which is a special case of the homography matrix that requires the focal length. If you're doing stitching, `HomographyBasedEstimator` is probably the way to go. (My guess is that it's doing RANSAC internally.)

Comment: yea, i tried to look for documentations on opencv site too but to no avail.

Comment: Thanks anyway! appreciated